# How to auto import 'svelte/transition' with 'sveltekit-autoimport'?

Tags: javascript, svelte, vite, sveltekit, sveltekit-autoimport

I'm trying to use [sveltekit-autoimport](https://github.com/yuanchuan/sveltekit-autoimport) version 1.6.10 to auto import `svelte/transition` module.

Inside `vite.config.js`

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'
import autoImport from 'sveltekit-autoimport'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    autoImport({
      components: ['./src/components'],
      module: {
        svelte: ['onMount', 'createEventDispatcher'],
        'svelte/transition': ['fly'],
        'svelte-apollo': ['mutation'],
      },
    }),
    svelte()
  ]
})
```

Everything is working fine, except: `'svelte/transition': ['fly']`

I also tried using different combinations and `mapping` instead of `module` but couldn't make it work.

```js
autoImport({
  mapping: {
    fly: `import { fly } from 'svelte/transition'`
  }
})
```

Any help will be really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This bug has been resolved in version 1.7.0](https://github.com/yuanchuan/sveltekit-autoimport/issues/34#issuecomment-1472937025)

You can use it now without problems as follows:

```html
<script>
  let visible = true
</script>


<label>
  <input type="checkbox" bind:checked={visible}>
  visible
</label>

{#if visible}
  <p in:fly={{ y: 200 }} out:fly={{ y: 200 }}>
    Fly in and out
  </p>
{/if}
```

Don't forget to add it first in `module` inside `vite.config.js`

```js
autoImport({
  module: {
    'svelte/transition': ['fly']
  }
})
```